# When to use Request.UrlReferrer and when Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Both returns the incoming url, Just to know When to use `Request.UrlReferrer` and when `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` and why?

Currently, in one of my application Urlreferrer is working in my local machine but its not working when went live?

Additionally, its most appreciable if anyone can guide any alternative of both Urlreferrer and HTTP_REFERRER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering to last question. Request.UrlReferrer returns an Uri object, so if UrlReferrer has bad format then you get an exception. It seems strange, but some times I have got it. HTTP_REFERER is a string.

Comment: +1 and thanks for this answer. @fravelgue is correct, an invalid uri for the referrer in the HTTP header will cause a `UriFormatException` if you attempt to access the `UrlReferrer` property. See my answer here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878458/httpcontext-current-request-servervariableshttp-referer-null?nah=1#28845912

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Request.ServerVariables[]` work in the live situation? It is my understanding that the two are identical.

Can it be that proxies and/or firewalls (at the server, the client or anywhere inbetween as an ISP) are stripping the referrer?

Comment: I checked there is no firewall

Comment: @Gaurav: if you tested it locally (and it worked) and now it is live you get "other" users, then those users (or their ISPs) can have firewalls etc.

Comment: Currently this is live in our own network and users are from same network, where it is working fine. But on live its not working