# HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use following code to get referring url in global.asax session_start:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

I tried using `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri but UrlReferrer` is also null.

but I am getting null. Can you please suggest me what is wrong or alternative?

Comment: I guess you could use `Request.UrlReferrer` for that.

Comment: There is no reason to down-vote a legitimate question. It may seem foolish what is being done here, but that doesn't make the question less valid.

Answer (score 6):

Not all user-agents *send* a referrer, some proxies/intermediaries *strip* the referrer, and often there simply **is** no referrer.

Just check whether `Request.UrlReferrer == null` at some point; if it is, don't try looking at `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`.

There is nothing "wrong" here, and nothing you can do about it. If you don't know where they came from, you'll just have to live with that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is about 2 1/2 years late but I couldn't find a thorough write up on the `UrlReferrer` property so I figured I would add this info here. @MarcGravell's answer is correct for the most part, but it misses one other possibility. The value for referrer specified in the HTTP header can also be an invalid uri.

For this reason, you should be careful when using the `UrlReferrer` property on `HttpRequest`. If you look at the code that is executed when `UrlReferrer` is called using something like ILSpy, you'll see that it tries to parse the value from the request header. If the value in that header is not a valid uri, you will get a `System.UriFormatException`.

What this means is that simply checking `UrlReferrer` for null before trying to access `AbsoluteUri` could leave you with unhandled exceptions if the referrer is not a valid uri. If you want either a valid `Uri` or `null`, you'll have to use `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` and then `Uri.TryParse`, or you'll have to wrap the `Request.UriReferrer == null` check in a `try-catch`.

I put together a quick demo to show the behavior of the `UrlReferrer` property. Take the following page as an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<html><body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>Referrer</td><td><%= GetUrlReferrer() %></td></tr>
        </table>
</body></html>
<script runat="server">
public string GetUrlReferrer()
{
    try
    {
        return Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "(None)" : Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] + " (from Server Variable)";
    }
}    
</script>
```

Set up this page to run under `http://localhost/urlreferrertest.aspx`, and then try calling it from Powershell with an invalid Uri for the referrer:

```
> $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
> $client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://www%2etest%2e.com/test.html")
> $client.DownloadString("http://localhost/urlreferrertest.aspx")
```

If you step through the code you'll see that the call to `Request.UrlReferrer` throws an exception, and that `http://www%2etest%2e.com/test.html` is returned by accessing the `ServerVariable`.